# Does wget check if specified user agent is allowed in robots.txt?

Tags: wget

If I specify a custom user agent for wget, eg "MyBot (info@mybot...)" Will wget check this in robots.txt as well, if the bot was banned, or only the general robot exclusions?

Comment: See the section titled **Robot Exclusion** in the `wget` documentation.

Comment: Thx that is why I am here :) That section does not say, whether wget will verify that my custom useragent is allowed. Just general robots.txt exclusions http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, and I have since noticed the same thing. Nowhere does it say what it looks for in `robots.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you specify your own user agent, Wget does not check for it in the robots.txt file. In fact, I believe I've found another bug in Wget while trying to answer your question. Even if you specify a custom User Agent, Wget seems to adhere to its own User Agent rules when parsing robots.txt. I have created a test case for this and will fix the implementation in Wget ASAP.

Now for the authoritative answer to your original question. The answer is no, because the in the source of Wget, you see the following comment preceding the function that parses the robots file for rules:

> /* Parse textual RES specs beginning with SOURCE of length LENGTH.
>   Return a specs objects ready to be fed to res_match_path.
>
> The parsing itself is trivial, but creating a correct SPECS object is
>   trickier than it seems, because RES is surprisingly byzantine if you
>   attempt to implement it correctly.
>
> A "record" is a block of one or more `User-Agent' lines followed by
>   one or more`Allow' or `Disallow' lines. Record is accepted by Wget if
>   one of the`User-Agent' lines was "wget", or if the user agent line
>   was "*".
>
> After all the lines have been read, we examine whether an exact
>   ("wget") user-agent field was specified. If so, we delete all the
>   lines read under "User-Agent: *" blocks because we have our own
>   Wget-specific blocks. This enables the admin to say:
>
> User-Agent: * Disallow: /
>
> User-Agent: google User-Agent: wget Disallow: /cgi-bin
>
> This means that to Wget and to Google, /cgi-bin is disallowed, whereas
>   for all other crawlers, everything is disallowed. res_parse is
>   implemented so that the order of records doesn't matter. In the case
>   above, the "User-Agent: *" could have come after the other one. */

Comment: This is a perfect answer. More than anyone could ask for. Thanks